# single page with several template cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new and discovered cakephp.

I'd like to make a single page website. I have two controllers with the classical functions: `index`, `add`, `edit` and `delete`.

The data is composed of two different lists, each in their own template
so when the visitors come, they'd see both lists on the homepage. But I don't know how to do that.

```
<?php


$this->start('all_series');
?>

<table class="table_media">
<tr>
<td> Titre </td>
<td> Langages </td>
<td> Créée le </td>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($series as $serie): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $serie->title ?></td>
    <td><?= $serie->languages ?></td>
    <td><?= $serie->created ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php $this->end();?>
```

This is an example in it's own template. The second list is similar. Now I want to put these lists in the homepage.

I am confused by cakePhp on that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this a template that needs to be available separately and also on the home page? Or is the home page the only place this will go?

Comment: You can add similar logic to home page. What is the probelm?

Comment: The home page is the only place it will go, I just don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the (I assume baked) Controllers to grab the data. You can access the tables data from within any Controller. Just make a HomepageController.php and use e.g.

```
$table1 = $this->getTableLocator()->get('table1Alias');
$query1 = $table1->find('all');

$table2 = $this->getTableLocator()->get('table2Alias');
$query2 = $table2->find('all');
```

Then pass both $query variables to the view and display it.